# Нужно ли закрывать соединение после каждого запроса SQL или нет?

Tags: c#, mono, производительность, sql, mysql

Нужно ли закрывать соединение после каждого запроса SQL или нет?

И как это повлияет на производительность?

Если не закрывать то что будет дальше происходить?

Comment: Не нужно. Совсем напротив. Дело в том что подключение-отключение от БД достаточно небыстрая операция.

> Если не закрывать то что будет дальше происходить?

Давайте определимся с языком/средой, о которой идет речь.

Comment: обновил теги, ОС Debian, несколько удаленных баз данных,

очень интенсивная работа с веб

Comment: @Merlin, "очень интенсивная работа с веб" - это сколько соединений (в смысле TCP connect) в секунду?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, согласно руководству "[Работаем с Mono: Часть 12. Взаимодействие с базами данных](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-Mono_12/)" можно использовать

> Pooling – при подключении к БД
> использовать соединение из пула или
> создавать новое (true – использовать
> из пула, но, если свободных соединений
> в пуле нет, то в подключении будет
> отказано).

Таким образом когда вы вызываете Close(), соединение не закрывается, а помещается в пул.

Так же можно установить таймаут соединения

```
mySqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 20;
```

Answer (score 4):

Постоянно открытого подключения, ожидающего действий пользователя, быть не должно. Подключение должно создаваться как реакция на какое-нибудь действие пользователя, в контексте этого подключения делаются все необходимые запросы, после чего подключение закрывается.

Comment: А как насчет пулов подключений, которые именно что держат открытыми пачку соединений и выдают по требованию?

А если БД вообще на другой машине?

Comment: Пулы подключения держат подключение в течение определённого времени, а не бесконечно. И потом, если использовать ADO.NET, то пулы работают неявно, разработчику не нужно самому об этом заботиться.

А что не так, если БД на другой машине?

Comment: > А что не так, если БД на другой машине?

Задержки на подключение/отключение будут еще больше. При большом кол-ве запросов это может будет заметно.

Comment: @Modus ну так ADO.NET будет постоянно пулы держать.